# CoreCLR internals: how CLR resolves length of array

Tags: c#, clr, coreclr

I've been trying to find out the implementation for `Length` property of `System.Array` class (just out of curiosity). So, in the official `dotnet/coreclr` repository I've found the definition of that class ([the link](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.CoreCLR.cs#:%7E:text=abstract%20partial%20class-,Array,-%3A%20ICloneable%2C%20IList%2C%20IStructuralComparable)), but I quite don't understand the code. So it goes:

```cs
public int Length => checked((int)Unsafe.As<RawArrayData>(this).Length);
```

What [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.as?view=net-5.0) say about `Unsafe.As` method:

> `Unsafe.As<T>(Object)` Casts the given object to the specified type.

So we are casting `System.Array`'s `this` instance to `RawArrayData` and getting the `Length` field of returned object.

Let's look at the `RawArrayData` inside `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers` class (it's a nested class, [the link](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.CoreCLR.cs#:%7E:text=internal%20class-,RawArrayData,-%7B)):

```cs
internal class RawArrayData
{
    public uint Length; // Array._numComponents padded to IntPtr
#if BIT64
    public uint Padding;
#endif
    public byte Data;
}
```

As we can see, it's just a class with empty fields, how does CoreCLR resolves the `RawArrayData.Length`?

Comment: The `Unsafe.As<RawArrayData>(this)` takes whatever memory `this` points to, and forcefully re-interprets it as a `RawArrayData`. So, whatever `this` points to, we'll interpret the first 4 bytes as being the length of the array. This matches how the CLR stores arrays: the first 4 bytes contains the length, then there's 4 bytes of padding on x64, then the data is stored.

Comment: When you create an array, you have to give it a length (either `var myArray = new SomeType[4];` or `var intArray = new []{1,2,3,4,5};`).  Once an array instance is created, its length never changes.  So, the array class stores the length in its data.  It doesn't need to count anything, or resolve anything, it's just there.

Comment: @canton7 thanks, it seems to be an answer to my question! Please post it as an answer for me to accept.

Comment: @Flydog57 oh, good point, I've forgotten about it!